# Biopython SeqIO: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, sequence, biopython, fasta

I am trying to filter out sequences using SeqIO but I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "paralog_warning_filter.py", line 61, in <module>
.
.
.
    SeqIO.write(desired_proteins, "filtered.fasta","fasta")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I checked other similar questions but still couldn't understand what is wrong with my script.

Here is the relevant part of the script I am trying:

```
fh=open('lineageV_paralog_warning_genes.fasta')
for s_record in SeqIO.parse(fh,'fasta'):
    name = s_record.id
    seq = s_record.seq
    for i in paralogs_in_all:
        if name.endswith(i):
            desired_proteins=seq
            output_file=SeqIO.write(desired_proteins, "filtered.fasta","fasta")
output_file
fh.close()
```

I have a separate `paralagos_in_all` list and that is the ID source. When I try to print `name` it returns a proper string id names which are in this format `>coronopifolia_tair_real-AT2G35040.1@10`.

Can you help me understand my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is like I already forgot but coukd be SeqIO.write needs SeqRecord object to be written. recordz = SeqRecord(
    Seq(sequenz),
    id="prova",
    name="prova",
    description="prova",
)

Comment: yep !!! see here : https://www.biostars.org/p/314630/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try and let us know (can't test your code ) :

```
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio import SeqIO
......
.......

desired_proteins = []

fh=open('lineageV_paralog_warning_genes.fasta')
for s_record in SeqIO.parse(fh,'fasta'):
    name = s_record.id
    seq = s_record.seq
    for i in paralogs_in_all:
        if name.endswith(i):
            # desired_proteins=SeqRecord( Seq(seq), id=name) ### here seq is already a Seq object see below
            desired_proteins.append(SeqRecord( seq, id=name, description="")) # description='' removes the <unknown description> that otherwise would be present 
            
            
output_file=SeqIO.write(desired_proteins, "filtered.fasta","fasta") ## don't know how to have SeqIO.write to append to file instead of re-writing all of it

fh.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However I got this error:

`NameError: name 'SeqRecord' is not defined`

I am importing Bio and SeqIO at the start of course.

Comment: Try  from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

Comment: Yes the previous one gave an error, but the last version worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: to 'append' write to a file handle like `with open("out.fa", "w") as f: SeqIO.write(prot, f, "fasta")`

Comment: @Chris_Rands got it :  `with open("out.fa", "a") as f: SeqIO.write(prot, f, "fasta")`  Cheers